# How to Download a File (from URL) in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, file

Update: This question used to ask about Google Cloud Storage, but I have since realized the issue actually is reproducable merely trying to save the download to local disk. Thus, I am rephrasing the question to be entirely about file downloads in Typescript and to no longer mention Google Cloud Storage.

---

When attempting to download and save a file in Typescript with [WebRequests](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-request) (though I experienced the same issue with `requests` and `request-promises`), all the code seems to execute correctly, but the resultant file is corrupted and cannot be viewed. For example, if I download an image, the file is not viewable in any applications.

```js
// Seems to work correctly
const download = await WebRequest.get(imageUrl);
// `Buffer.from()` also takes an `encoding` parameter, but it's unclear how to determine the encoding of a download
const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(download.content);
// I *think* this line is straightforward
const imageByteArray = new Uint8Array(imageBuffer);
// Saves a corrupted file
const file = fs.writeFileSync("/path/to/file.png", imageByteArray);
```

I suspect the issue lies within the `Buffer.from` call not correctly interpreting the downloaded content, but I'm not sure how to do it right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Could you edit the question to explain what exactly `WebRequest` is?  Are you working with some library?

Comment: Done! Apologies - I don't use JavaScript or npm often and had mistakenly concluded that `WebRequest` was ubiquitous (ala Python's `requests`).

Comment: I would actually say that "request" and "request-promise" are more common for node, if you're looking for some well-traveled libraries.

Comment: Those two libraries also work, but result in the same error I'm seeing with `WebRequest` - a bloated file corrupted so as to be unviewable as an image. I'm strongly suspecting there's some specific manipulation I need to make (encoding/decoding, or the like) on my raw download before it is fit for re-uploading.

Answer (score 0):

From what I saw in the examples for web-request, `download.content` is just a string.  If you want to upload a string to Cloud Storage using the node SDK, you can use [File.save](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#save), passing that string directly.

Alternatively, you could use one the solutions seen [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node/issues/2334).

Comment: This was one of the many things I tried early on, and it almost works, except the resultant file in Cloud Storage is roughly twice the size of the actual asset and corrupted to be unviewable as an image. Interestingly, passing `download.content` directly into the Storage.File object has the exact same output as going through all the ImageBuffer steps, so those additional lines don't seem to do anything.

Comment: If your content is binary data, like an image, you shouldn't be accessing it as a string.  You'll need to use your HTTP library in such a way that you get a buffer or stream so that you can pass the raw binary data into Cloud Storage.